# Effect on Metal-Phosphine Bond if Metal centre gets oxidised

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state

Looking at the Octahedral complex, the chromium is a $d^6$ complex and, if the Chromium bond gets oxidised, it will have lesser electrons to donate to phosphine's $\sigma^{*}$ orbital.

This effect is similar to the CO bond. If the metal centre is oxidised, there is lesser electrons donated to the $\pi^{*}$ orbitals.

And when there is lesser electrons donated to the ligand's antibonding orbital ($\sigma^{*}, \pi^{*}$) orbital, it means that their Bond Order will be higher which stabilises the molecule (shorter bond length). However, this is only true for CO-Metal bond, length, but not true for the Phospine-Metal bond length. The P-M bond length would actually be weaker after oxidization of the metal centre. WHy is this the case?

[image]